# Can I safely delete the administration notification log file (.nfy)?

Tags: db2, database-administration, db2-luw

I have a `.nfy` dump file in my client system which is taking too much space. It has been last updated on 4 August. Will it be OK if I delete it? Will it be permanently deleted or DB2 will create a new one?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly safe to delete the administration notification log file, and yes, it will be re-created as necessary by the instance.

You can also enable automatic rotation of this file and the diagnostic log file (`db2diag.log`) by setting the `diagsize` instance configuration parameter, for example

```
db2 update dbm cfg using diagsize 1024
```

The command above instructs the instance to create 10 rotating log files, each with the maximum size of 1024 MB. Once the 10th file reaches the maximum size, the oldest of the 10 files will be deleted and a new file created.

Note that you will need to restart the DB2 instance for the new parameter value to take effect.

More info [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0054862.html?lang=en).

Comment: I have deleted the .nfy which was 300 mb file , and as expected 300 mb more free space was available in the filesystem .But within 4-5 hours  again 300mb space was filled, when I checked I saw several  dump files with names like (667734.20429.000.dump.bin) with 3-7 mb size got created (after deleting), which  filled up more than 300 mb space. What approach should I be taking, can I delete these files too? or need to take up a different approach so that these files do not get created.

Comment: Dump files are generated when the DB2 instance encounters non-recoverable errors. You need to analyze the log files and resolve the problem. Contact IBM support if necessary.